# How to cut some lines from a file and paste them at certain position in a same file using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have a file named 'test.txt' that contains some text as follows:

```
<<Title here>>

Hello there

Please cut me and paste somewhere else

Bye there
```

I want to cut the line-

```
Please cut me and paste somewhere else
```

And, paste them at the top after **Title here** as following:-

```
<<Title here>>

Please cut me and paste somewhere else

Hello there

Bye there
```

I want to do cut-paste operations in the same file using python. How can I achieve the same?

Comment: Is this something you have to do repeatedly?  Because otherwise, why wouldn't you just use a text editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were overthinking this.  It's not a hard problem.

```
parts = open('x.txt').read().split('\n\n')
parts.insert( 1, parts.pop(2))
print('\n\n'.join(parts))
```